# "Constant Expression required" error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and I am trying to write a simple program that copies a sheet to another sheet and then pastes it with some of the rows selectively deleted. As part of my program I am trying to simply save the number of used rows as an integer, what I call shorterLen in the following code. However, when I try to construct an array of length shorterLen, I get a compile error: "constant expression required." I don't understand this because I the code I am using to find the number of used rows (Sheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.count) should be outputing a constant integer. Also I tried it before and it was working fine. Is there something I am missing? I have asked a friend who is an expert with VBA and he didn't know. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim i As Integer
Dim numRows As Integer
numRows = Sheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.count
Debug.Print (numRows)
shorterLen = numRows - 11

Dim securityInd(shorterLen) As Integer

For i = 1 To shorterLen

If Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4)) Then
securityInd(i) = 1
Else:
securityInd(i) = 0
End If
Next i
ActiveSheet.Copy
Sheets.Add.Name = "sheet1"
Sheets("sheet1").select
ActiveSheet.paste

For i = 1 To numRows - 11
If securityInd(i) = 0 Then
Sheets("sheet1").Rows(i).Delete
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change an array dynamically like that use  `ReDim` instead of `Dim`

`Dim` is for declaration of type in general.  `Redim` Is specifically for changing array size, and setting a dynamic arrays size for the first time counts as changing.

Comment: thank you, this got rid of that error. I am now dealing with a diffeent error -- namely that my new sheet is being created in a different workbook and without any content -- but you still fixed my problem. I am stilla  bit confused though ... that was the first time I has declared securityInd, so I was not "redimensioning" it. Why did I have to use Redim in this situation?

Comment: thank you. but my array is not dynamic. I just want to make a static array of size shorterLen

Comment: @paul because you want to change it at run time, it _is_ dynamic.  A static array is declared as a fixed size, eg `Dim A(1 to 10) As Integer`.  Done like that it can't be Redim'd.

Comment: Interesting. I guess cab has some fundamental differences from the languages I am used to such as c and java. Or maybe I just don't understand. What do you mean by change it at runtime? I am only declaring it once just like every other variable

Comment: What I mean is you don't know the size of array you want until you run your code.  Therefore you can't declare a fixed size.  I guess the jargon may be a little different, but surely the concept is common enough.